# Switch PHP version on Centos 6.4

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

I'm using CentOS 6.4 and I got Apache 2.2 and MySQL, but the PHP version is 5.5.1 which is a problem for me, because the application which we develop is working with php 5.3 and lower versions. I use this tutorial to install everything: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Bust I can't find any answer in web to configure the server correctly to switch php version with cgi or fastcgi.

Can you help me?

Comment: How did you end up with PHP 5.5.1?

Comment: Running PHP via CGI is not a very good idea. And if it's apache pre-fork then I'd recommend mod_php over fastCGI

Comment: @symcbean, just give me the steps and I'll try :) MichaelHampton, I just follow the steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove php with all its packages, disable repository from which you installed it (there is any for 5.5.1? wow) and install php package from CentOS base repository - there is 5.3.3.

1. stop apache.
2. `yum remove php\*`
3. set `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/<php5.5.51-repository-file>`
4. `yum install php` (check if yum will catch correct version)
5. edit /etc/php.ini as you need and start apache.

Comment: Hi, this is alternative way. I need a way to switch versions fast. I don't need to install/config reinstall/reconfig and etc.

Comment: This is as fast as it can be. `php.ini` will be saved after unistallation as `php.ini.rpmsave` so you can use it. I'm not sure if all config options are same for 5.5 and 5.3.